# As of August 2020, are Social Security Offices in the US closed due to COVID-19?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, social-security

Are all social security offices around the country (USA) closed? I can't find a clear answer. Also, if yes, why? In many states things are really up and running again.

Comment: You might clarify what you mean by "closed".  It could be either "not operating" or "not accepting in-person visits from the public".  Certainly the first is not true, as my neighbor recently (a couple of months ago) applied and is now receiving benefits. Though she did everything over the web.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are all social security offices around the country (USA) closed?

No, the offices are open by appointment only.

[What safety protocols must I follow to visit a Social Security office?](https://www.ssa.gov/coronavirus/) (Select: Getting Help from Social Security)
Date: July 17, 2020

> Due to COVID-19, you must have a scheduled appointment to enter an
> office. Only you may enter the facility unless you have made
> additional arrangements when you scheduled your appointment.
>
> Effective July 20, 2020, everyone must complete a self-assessment
> checklist before allowed entry. You will not be permitted to enter if
> you answer yes to any of these questions:
>
> 1. Do you have any of the following symptoms?
>
> [...]
>
> 2. In the last 14 days, have you:
>
> [...]
>
> If you answer YES to any of these questions, or if you feel ill, you
> will not be allowed to enter. Call the office to reschedule your
> appointment. If you do not have the phone number, use our Office
> Locator to find the phone number.
>
> If you can answer NO to both questions, you must wear a face covering
> over your mouth and nose to enter the facility. If you do not have a
> mask, we will provide you with one. If you are unable to wear a face
> covering, call the office and ask to speak with the manager.
>
> For your safety, Social Security employees are required to follow the
> same self-assessment checklist and are required to wear a face
> covering.